# Vertically center right detail UILabel in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, vertical-alignment

I have a very basic prototype table view cell set up with the Right Detail style. The label that is available on the right is by default vertically centered. But if you change the font size from the default 17 to say 12, then you can see it's no longer centered - pushed down too far.

[image]

You can tell when you double click the label that its frame is aligned to the bottom of the cell.

[image]

How could I vertically align it in the middle instead? Thanks!

To see the issue:
1. Drag out Table View Controller
2. Change style to Right Detail
3. Select the right label and change font size to 12

Comment: how about just re-posioning it again after changing the size? it should snap to the guiding lines.

Comment: That's not possible - you can't change its x, y, width, or height in storyboard. I didn't manually add that label, it's the default Right Detail label.

Comment: than your should create your own cell  subclass and create the interface yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in Right Detail table view cell style is doing the right thing. It just isn't what you expect. You expect it to be vertically aligned within the cell. But Apple thinks both the Title and Detail labels should be **baseline** aligned.

If you indeed want to vertically align the Detail label, you should create your own custom UITableViewCell subclass. To do that, you can add both a Right Detail cell and a custom cell. Copy both labels from the Right Detail cell to your custom cell. Copy over x, y, width, and height so that your custom cell looks exactly the same as the Right Detail cell. Then you can change your font size. Finally, add the necessary constraints for your labels. For the Details label, you obviously want to add the vertically align constraint.

Hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: Perhaps I'll think it over some more, see how I feel about baseline alignment instead. That's a lot of work to mimic something I can get for free minus the center alignment. :p

Comment: The built-in table view cell styles are fine for a prototype app. However, for a release app, you almost always create your own custom subclass anyway. So it is extra work, but not too much :)

Comment: It continued to bug me so I did create my own style. Indeed it wasn't too much work - thanks for the suggestion.